# Используя Java Stream API, вывести:

Tags: java, api, потоки-данных, java-stream

Номера всех автомобилей, имеющих черный цвет или нулевой пробег. // filter + map
Количество уникальных моделей в ценовом диапазоне от 700 до 800 тыс. // distinct + filter

```
о656са121|LadaVesta|Blue|2000|750000
н455сх178|ToyotaCamry|Black|500|1500000
а787ук197|KiaRio|Green|0|795000
р435ав777|BMW|Black|3560|3000000
```

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("auto.txt"))) {
            reader.lines()
                    .forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Auto {
    private String carNumber;
    private String carModel;
    private String carColor;
    private int mileage;
    private int price;
    
    public Auto(String carNumber, String carModel, String carColor, int mileage, int price) {
        this.carNumber = carNumber;
        this.carModel = carModel;
        this.carColor = carColor;
        this.mileage = mileage;
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public String getCarNumber() {
        return carNumber;
    }

    public void setCarNumber(String carNumber) {
        this.carNumber = carNumber;
    }

    public String getCarModel() {
        return carModel;
    }

    public void setCarModel(String carModel) {
        this.carModel = carModel;
    }

    public String getCarColor() {
        return carColor;
    }

    public void setCarColor(String carColor) {
        this.carColor = carColor;
    }

    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }

    public void setMileage(int mileage) {
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите больше подробностей возникшей проблемы и отформатируйте код

Comment: о656са121|LadaVesta|Blue|2000|750000
н455сх178|ToyotaCamry|Black|500|1500000
а787ук197|KiaRio|Green|0|795000
р435ав777|BMW|Black|3560|300 Это строки из файла auto.txt

Comment: Я так понимаю нужно сделать сплит строк.Но не пойму как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки разбиваются методом `String::split`, но в данном случае надо заэкранировать символ `|`, так как он используется в регулярных выражениях как оператор OR: `line -> line.split("\\|")`

> *Номера всех автомобилей, имеющих черный цвет или нулевой пробег. // `filter + map`*

```
reader.lines()                        // Stream<String>
      .map(line -> line.split("\\|")) // Stream<String[]>
      .filter(arr -> "Black".equalsIgnoreCase(arr[2]) // цвет чёрный
                  || 0 == Integer.parseInt(arr[3])   // или пробег нулевой
      )
      .forEach(arr -> System.out.println(arr[0])); // номер
```

Вывод:

```
н455сх178
а787ук197
р435ав777
```

> *Количество уникальных моделей в ценовом диапазоне от 700 до 800 тыс. // `distinct + filter`*
> Здесь выводятся именно *уникальные модели*

```
long countFrom700to800 = reader.lines()                  // Stream<String>
      .map(line -> line.split("\\|")) // Stream<String[]>
      .filter(arr -> 700_000 <= Integer.parseInt(arr[4]) // от 700 тыс.
                  && Integer.parseInt(arr[4]) < 800_000  // до 800 тыс.
      )
      .map(arr -> arr[1]) // модель
      .distinct()
      .count(); // количество моделей
System.out.println(countFrom700to800);
```

Вывод:

```
2
```

`distinct` по полным строкам в данном случае не имеет особого смысла, так каждая строка содержит уникальный номер машины и различающуюся цену, а так получается именно количество уникальных *моделей*.

Comment: Спасибо.Теперь понял в чем моя ошибка была.